# Getting Bitlocker status via batch script and Net View

Tags: batch-file, pipeline, bitlocker

I've been trying to create an easier way for my team to get the bitlocker status of devices on our network. After checking through a bunch of seperate answers on here and other sites I've managed to cobble together an *almost* working batch script, however it doesn't seem to be pulling the entry correctly. Code is below:

```
@echo off
color a
title BitLocker Checking
:start
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /F %%a in ('net view') do (
   set line=%%a
   if "!line:~0,2!" equ "\\" (
      set /A i+=1
      echo [!i!]        !line:~2!
      set comp[!i!]=!line:~2!
   )
)

echo.
echo.
echo Choose a computer.
choice /c 12345678 >nul
set name=!comp[%errorlevel%]!

cls
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('manage-bde -status -computername %name% ^| find "Conversion Status"') do set derp=%%B
if "%name%"=="" goto start
echo The status of %name% is %derp%
echo.
echo.
echo %derp% | clip
echo. %derp% copyied to clipboard.
echo.
echo Press any key.
pause 
goto start
```

When I take the `manage-bde -status -computername %name% | find "Conversion Status"` line in isolation and provide it with a computername, it seems to pull the conversion status line correctly (e.g. "Conversion Status :    Fully Decrypted" if bitlocker is off on the machine).
However if left in context of the batch file, it outputs "The status of computernamegoeshere is" and then a blank, as if it's not getting the data from the Find command into the variable %B.

Anyone have any suggestions? It's been a while since I've written batch commands so a bit rusty.

Comment: I don't see any `[]` characters in the resulting output, so your `delims=[]` seems to be wrong. What version of Windows are you running this on?

Comment: Shouldn't `if "%name%"=="" goto start` happen before the `for` loop?

Comment: @jwdonahue Windows 10 currently, but aiming to push it out on a bit of a range due to some of our system setups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the extra white space in the output is messing with you. On Win10 command line, this works for me:

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %A in ('manage-bde -status -computername %COMPUTERNAME% ^| findstr Conversion') do echo %A %B
```

Resulting in output (minus prompt noise):

```
Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
```

So you need to remove the `delims=[]`, change `tokens=1,2` to `tokens=1,*` and whether you use find or findstr is up you. My preference is findstr.

Comment: Thanks @jwdonahue. Had to add the extra % symbols back in (%%A and %%B) but seems to work now.